How is a shared JDBC pool configured?
We're using a Payara 5 server with 4 application instances. A JDBC pool is configured with 5 set as the maximum number of connections in the pool. A JDBC resource pointing at the JDBC connection pool is also created and the cluster is set as the target.
I would have expected that all 4 instances can only use at most 5 connections in total. However, in our database tool I can see that each instance can make 5 connections, so the total number of connections is 20. With the given setup, I thought the pool is shared between all instances, but it's not.
The JNDI name is used in the persistence.xml as the value for the <jta-data-source> element.
Why is the pool not shared among all instances?
If anyone has a pointer to the documentation which could clarify this, this would really help.

I don't have a pointer to the documentation but it's true that connection pools are not synchronized among instances. Each instance has its own connection pool with the same configuration. If max connections is 5 and you have 4 instances, then total number of connections would be 20.

I think the reason for this is that it's significantly difficult to synchronize connection pools among instances and ensure that the total number of connections is not higher than max connections configured for the pool. There are also many situations that would need to be handled - when an instance is stopped, then more connections would be available per instance. If another instance is started, then other instances would need to drop connections to free them for the new instance. You may raise a feature request on the Payara project and see if Payara would implement this feature.

If you need this feature, maybe Payara company can add it to Payara for you for a fee. My company, OmniFish, could implement it in GlassFish.
